# Updating multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple fields on admin panel user can add field and delete the fields as well while adding it I placed simple insert query with foreach loop but it is difficult to understand the concept for updating that fields if user deletes a field or updates it is not working if I delete 1 field and update it it deletes 2 or more then 2 fields and when I try to update it is not updating well update issue is due i would be making some mistake with query. But main thing is about logic which I am unable to build it properly need help.

Update query

```
$video_link = $_POST['video_link'];
$old_links  = count($video_link);
if(isset($_POST['video_id'])) {
    $video_id   = $_POST['video_id'];
    $total_id   = count($video_id); 
} else {
    $video_id   = '';
}
$video_links = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM video_slides WHERE model_id = '$model_id'");
$total_links = mysqli_num_rows($video_links);

$video_link = sizeof($video_link) - 1;
if($total_links >= 1) {
    for($i = 0; $i<=$video_link; $i++) {
        if(empty($video_id[$i])) {
            mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `video_slides`(`embeded_link``, `model_id`) VALUES ('$video_link[$i]', '$model_id')");
        }
        $query2 = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `video_slides` SET `embeded_link`='$video_link[$i]' WHERE id='$video_id[$i]'");
        if($video_link < $total_links) {
            $new_total = $total_links-sizeof($video_link);
            for($j = 0; $j<=$new_total; $j++) {
                mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM video_slides WHERE id='$video_id[$j]'");
            }
        }
    }
        } else {
            for($i = 0; $i<=$video_link; $i++) {
                if(empty($video_id[$i])) {
                    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `video_slides`(`embeded_link``, `model_id`) VALUES ('$video_link[$i]', '$model_id')");
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is my form fields

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Video Slides <input type="button" class="add_field_button btn blue" value="Add Field" /></label>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <?php 
        $sql3 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM video_slides WHERE model_id = '".$data['id']."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql3) == 0) {
    ?>
    <div class="new">
        <input type="text" id="video_link" size="20" name="video_link[]" placeholder="Embeded Video Link" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <?php 
        } else {
            while($video = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {
    ?>
    <div class="new">
        <input type="text" id="video_link" size="20" name="video_link[]" placeholder="Embeded Video Link" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $video['embeded_link']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $video['id']; ?>" name="video_id[]" />
        <a class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
    <?php } } ?>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you are doing wrong logic

Comment: Yes I do realize though but I am still confused can you help me out ??

Comment: please check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need only these thing why you making complex coding

```
$video_link = $_POST['video_link'];

//First Remove All ID
mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM video_slides WHERE model_id='$model_id'");

//Then After insert updated data
foreach($video_link as $key=>$val){
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `video_slides`(`embeded_link`, `model_id`) VALUES ('$val', '$model_id')");
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\primi\dashboard\includes\functions.php on line

Comment: Hey Why I was going in deep to complicate things lol it worked for me but please you made some incorrect formatting in your answer can you check ??

Answer (score 1):

you should try to outsource your db connections in a separate class - this will lead to better readable code. An ORM like Doctrine can definitely help you to better understand your own code.